# how to pass String value to all ViewController in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, session, global-variables

I have two textFields.One is username and second is password.When i submit two values pass to Json .If you username and password is there in Database.I get response username.
But Now i need that userName pass to all ViewControllers in my app Please help me 
thanks in Advanced.Please give me any idea.

Comment: store user name in NSUserDefaults

Comment: @karthikeyan thanks but Please explain to me  how to username   use to  Next ViewControls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

in your `firstviewcontroller`...

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:your texfield.txt forKey:@"username"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


and access anywhere you want like this

    NSString *username=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
    NSLog(@"%@",username);
```

it will display which entered in text filed

finally u need to remove the value from `NSUserDefaults`

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeobjectForKey:@"username"];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create variable in AppDelegate file.

IN AppDelegate.h file

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSString *username;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *username;
```

IN AppDelegate.m file

```
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize username;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //your other code.....
    self.username=@"";
}
```

Create AppDelegate object and set its value where you are submitting values to json

```
AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
delegate.username = @"ABC";
```

create AppDelegate object in all viewcontroller and access username variable

```
AppDelegate *delegate=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
nslog(@"%@",delegate.username);
```